# Tensor sum of two operators

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, tensor-products

Let $E$ be a complex Hilbert space. Let $E\overline{\otimes}E$ denotes the completion,
endowed with a reasonable uniform cross-norm of the algebraic tensor product $E\otimes E$.

> **Definition:** Let $A,B\in \mathcal{L}(E)$, the tensor sum of $A$ and $B$ is defined by 
>   $$A\oplus B:=(A\otimes I)+(I\otimes B)\in \mathcal{L}(E\overline{\otimes}E).$$

Clearly, if $A$ and $B$ are normal operators then so is $A\oplus B$.

> Assume that $A\oplus B$ is normal, it is true that $A$ is normal and $B$ is normal?

A short calculation shows that $A\oplus B$ is normal if and only if 
$$([A^*,A]\otimes I)+(I\otimes [B^*,B])=0.$$
It is possible to show that $[A^*,A]=[B^*,B]=0$?

Comment: If $E \overline{\otimes} E$ is only given some cross-norm, then what does it mean for an operator in $\mathcal{L}(E\overline\otimes E)$ to be _normal_?

Comment: Observe that $\exp (A \oplus B) =( \exp A) \otimes (\exp B)$, so the problem almost reduces to the exponentials and tensor products, ...

Comment: @MatthewDaws Thank you for your answer. $A\oplus B:=(A\otimes I)+(I\otimes B)\in \mathcal{L}(E\overline{\otimes}E)$ is normal if and only if $(A\oplus B)^*(A\oplus B)=(A\oplus B)(A\oplus B)^*$

Comment: @Student: I guess my question was really: if $E\overline\otimes E$ is not a Hilbert space, what does the _adjoint_ of $A\oplus B$ mean?

Comment: @MatthewDaws In my question $E\overline{\otimes}E$ denotes the completion,
endowed with a reasonable uniform cross-norm of the algebraic tensor product $E\otimes E$. So $E\overline{\otimes}E$ is Hilbert. Howerver $E\otimes E$ is not necessary Hilbert.

Comment: @Student Is the Banach space projective tensor product, under your meaning, a reasonable uniform crossnorm (I think it is).  If so, then $E \widehat\otimes E$ is a completed Banach space which is not a Hilbert space...

Comment: $E\overline{\otimes}E$ denotes the completion,
 of the algebraic tensor product $E\otimes E$. So it is Hilbert. Do you agree with me? Thanks

Comment: Yes, I agree.  That this is the "Hilbert space tensor product", and _not_ an arbitrary crossnorm...  It's confusing when your question says "a" uniform cross-norm, as if there was some choice...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let's start with a general lemma.  Let $E,F$ be Banach spaces, $E\overline\otimes F$ be the completion of a reasonable crossnorm.  Let $\newcommand{\mc}{\mathcal}T\in\mc L(E), S\in\mc L(F)$ be such that $T\otimes I = I\otimes S$.  Then $T=S$ is a scalar multiple of the identity.

This follows, as pick $f\in F, f^*\in F^*$ with $f^*(f)=1$.  Then
$$ T(e) = f^*(f) T(e) = f^*(S(f)) e \qquad (e\in E). $$
Thus $T = \alpha I$ where $\alpha = f^*(S(f))\in\mathbb C$.  Then $\alpha I\otimes I = I\otimes S$ so $S=\alpha I$.

So if your case, we get that $[A^*,A] = -[B^*,B]$ is a scalar multiple of the identity.  Now use the famous result that the commutant of two bounded operators cannot be a non-zero multiple of the identity.  So $A$ and $B$ are normal.